# Is it possible to open two websockets connection using SignalR package in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, signalr

I have been working with SignalR package for a while, so now I have a task which requires me to create two websockets connection.  One channel is for taking about 50 photos (it comes from server having about 2MB size for each, which is pretty big), the second is for getting time, user's auth, keep user's data, so my question is:

**How can I open two websockets connection concurrently?**

I have read that the websocket works synchronously and it is impossible to make it asynchronous (I guess?...), so may be, someone have had the same issue and solved it?

Now with SignalR package I need to start my websockets connection every time I want to use request to the server. For example, now it looks like this:

The first request on  page

```
 Future<String> getTime()async{
    //some code for building url which I took from from SignalR official docs
    
    await connection.start()
    hubconnection.invoke('getTime');
    }
```

the second request on this page

```
Future<String> getUsersData()async{
    //some code for building url which I took from from SignalR official docs
    
    await connection.start()
    hubconnection.invoke('getUsersData');
    }
```

So I am not sure about this line:  `await connection.start()` because I think this means that every time I go to a page where there can be up to five such requests, the websocket starts every time, which greatly affects the performance of the app. Is it possible to make this line shared between all requests once or is there some way to improve the work?

So after this research I was thinking may be I can open two websockets request to make workload less?

Comment: official answer from package's developer: https://github.com/AS-Devs/signalr_flutter/issues/46